# Statistical Process Control Charts in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, statistics, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm hoping you can point me in the right direction.

I'm trying to generate a control chart (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_chart) using SQL Server 2008. Creating a basic control chart is easy enough. I'd just calculate the mean and standard deviations and then plot them.

The complex bit (for me at least) is that I would like the chart to reset the mean and the control limits when a step change is identified.

Currently I'm only interested in a really simple method of identifying a step change, 5 points appearing consecutively above or below the mean. There are more complex ways of identifying them (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Electric_rules) but I just want to get this off the ground first.

The process I have sort of worked out is:

1. Aggregate and order by month and year, apply row numbers.
2. Calculate overall mean
3. Identify if each data item is higher, lower or the same as the mean, tag with +1, -1 or 0.
4. Identify when their are 5 consecutive data items which are above or below the mean (currently using a cursor).
5. Recalculate the mean if 5 points are above or 5 points are below the mean.
6. Repeat until end of table.

Is this sort of process possible in SQL server? It feels like I maybe need a recursive UDF but recursion is a bit beyond me!

A nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I ended up just using WHILE loops to iterate through. I won't post full code but the steps were:

1. Set up a user defined table data type in order to pass data into a stored procedure parameter.
2. Wrote accompanying stored procedure that uses row numbers and while loops to iterate along each data value in the input table and then uses the current row number to do set based processing on a subset of the input data (to check if following 5 points are above/below mean and recalculate the mean and standard deviations when this flag is tripped).
3. Outputs table with original values, row numbers, months, mean values, upper control limit and lower control limit.

I've also got one up and running that works based on full Nelson rules and will also state which test the data has failed.

Currently it's only been used by me as I develop it further so I've set up an Excel sheet with some VBA to dynamically construct a SQL string which it passes to a pivot table as the command text. That way you can repeatedly ping the USP with different data sets and also change a few of the other parameters on how the procedure runs (such as adjusting control limits and the like).

Ultimately I want to be able to pass the resulting data to Business Objects reports and dashboards that we're working on.